# Using If-else inside a class.

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can we use `if-else statement` inside a Javascript class?

I was working in react stateful class.

Inside the class I did something like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Aux from '../../HOC/Aux.js';
import Burger from '../../burger/burger.js'
import BuildControls from '../../burger/Build-Control/build-controls.js';
class BurgerBuilder extends Component {
state = {
    ingredient: {
      salad: 0,
      bacon: 0,
      cheese: 0,
      meat: 0
    },
    totalPrice: 4,
    purchaseable: false
  }

//Something 

if (this.state.totalPrice != 4) {
  let newState = {
    ...this.state.ingredient
  }
  this.setState({ingredient: newState})
}
```

but then then it started throwing this error

```
Unexpected token (63:4)

  61 | 
  62 | 
> 63 | if (this.state.totalPrice != 4) {
     |     ^
  64 |   let newState = {
  65 |     ...this.state.ingredient
  66 |   }
```

If we can use if-else statement, then any idea why isn't this working?

Comment: `if-else statement` should be in a `function` or inside `constructor` at-least.

Comment: No. If you want conditions, do it in the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move that logic to a method `setIngredientState` and call it form the `constructor`

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Aux from '../../HOC/Aux.js';
import Burger from '../../burger/burger.js'
import BuildControls from '../../burger/Build-Control/build-controls.js';
class BurgerBuilder extends Component {
  state = {
    ingredient: {
      salad: 0,
      bacon: 0,
      cheese: 0,
      meat: 0
    },
    totalPrice: 4,
    purchaseable: false
  }

  constructor() {
    this.setIngredientState();
  }

  //Something

  setIngredientState() {
    if (this.state.totalPrice != 4) {
      let newState = {
        ...this.state.ingredient
      }
      this.setState({
        ingredient: newState
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the if-statements inside functions when working with components.

You can either do it when the component is mounting, or when it is updating, like this:

```
*/ This will only occur once, at the moment the component is mounted */
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.state.totalPrice != 4) {
    let newState = {
      ...this.state.ingredient
    }
    this.setState({ingredient: newState})
  }
}

// This will happen every time a prop or state changes, which triggers a re-render of the component. This can trigger a recursive loop if you're not careful
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.totalPrice != 4) {
    let newState = {
      ...this.state.ingredient
    }
    this.setState({ingredient: newState})
  }
}
```

You can also set the if-statements when the component is rendering like this:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.totalPrice != 4) {
    let newState = {
      ...this.state.ingredient
    }
    this.setState({ingredient: newState})
  }
}
```

PS. Also note that you shouldn't use `!=` when comparing values in Javascript, it's better to use `!==` since it also compares the type and not only the value. In your case "4" and 4 is the same.